# With a varargs method, is it possible to determine if an object should be passed inline?

Tags: java

I am working with the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library specifically, but this is a more general question.

**Is it possible to skip an argument based on a condition when calling a varargs method?**

Consider the following example:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = "One";
        String str2 = "Two";
        String str3 = "Three";
        String str4 = "Four";
        String str5 = "Five";

        boolean excludeOne = false;
        boolean excludeTwo = false;
        boolean excludeThree = true;
        boolean excludeFour = false;
        boolean excludeFive = false;

        print(
                str1,
                str2,
                str3, // Can I skip this argument if excludeThree = true?
                str4,
                str5
        );

    }

    private static void print(Object... items) {

        for (Object item : items) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**My Use Case:** I am working to export a `TableView` to CSV, but depending on certain factors, one of more columns may or may not need to be included in that output. So I need a way to determine, at runtime, if that column should be included when calling the `CSVPrinter.printRecord(Object... values)` method.

I know I could build a list of valid items first and pass that to the method:

```
List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
if (!excludeOne) filteredList.add(str1);
if (!excludeTwo) filteredList.add(str2);
if (!excludeThree) filteredList.add(str3);
if (!excludeFour) filteredList.add(str4);
if (!excludeFive) filteredList.add(str5);

print(filteredList.toArray());
```

Just wondering if there is a shorter, in-line way of determining the arguments.

Comment: Building up an array would be what I would do. Alternatively, I would probably not use varargs at all, and use a Builder pattern instead.

Comment: @DanielPryden - The library I'm using uses the varargs for its method.

Comment: could you do `print(excludeOne ? "" : str1, etc)`? then `for (Object item : items) { if(!item.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(item);}
        }`

Comment: @Sedrick - That would not quite work because `""` would still be a value, albeit an empty value. So in my example, it would still print a blank line. Even worse, in my real-world application, I would need to pass `null` instead and that would not be desired either.

Comment: You can check for that in the method.

Comment: @Sedrick - I cannot because the method is from a 3rd-party library. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no syntax to change the length of a varargs array based on a runtime condition. If the length of the array is only determined at runtime, it must be passed as a single array argument (like your `filteredList.toArray()` example).

Reference: [Java Language Specification 15.12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2) says:

> If `m` is being invoked with *k ≠ n* actual argument expressions [...], then the argument list (e<sub>1</sub>, ..., e<sub>n-1</sub>, e<sub>n</sub>, ..., e<sub>k</sub>) is evaluated as if it were written as (e<sub>1</sub>, ..., e<sub>n-1</sub>, `new |T[]|` { e<sub>n</sub>, ..., e<sub>k</sub> }), where `|T[]|` denotes the erasure (§4.6) of `T[]`.
>
> The argument expressions (possibly rewritten as described above) are now evaluated to yield *argument values*. Each argument value corresponds to exactly one of the method's *n* formal parameters.

In your case, this means that if you have five actual argument expressions in your function call, the function will always receive an `Object[]` array with exactly five elements. You can't have any more or any less: the number of elements in the array is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create some type of helper method to return the actual things that need to be passed.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str1 = "One";
    String str2 = "Two";
    String str3 = "Three";
    String str4 = "Four";
    String str5 = "Five";

    boolean excludeOne = false;
    boolean excludeTwo = false;
    boolean excludeThree = true;
    boolean excludeFour = false;
    boolean excludeFive = false;

    print(helperMethod(excludeOne ? "" : str1,
            excludeTwo ? "" : str2,
            excludeThree ? "" : str3, // Can I skip this argument if excludeThree = true?
            excludeFour ? "" : str4,
            excludeFive ? "" : str5)
    );

}

public static Object[] helperMethod(Object... items)
{
    List<String> returnItems = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (!items[i].toString().isEmpty()) {
            returnItems.add(items[i].toString());
        }
    }

    return returnItems.toArray();
}

private static void print(Object... items)
{

    for (Object item : items) {
        if (!item.toString().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

> Here is a version that accepts objects.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str1 = "One";
    String str2 = "Two";
    String str3 = "Three";
    String str4 = "Four";
    String str5 = "Five";

    TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject("One");
    TestObject testObject2 = new TestObject("Two");
    TestObject testObject3 = new TestObject("Three");
    TestObject testObject4 = new TestObject("Four");
    TestObject testObject5 = new TestObject("Five");

    boolean excludeOne = false;
    boolean excludeTwo = false;
    boolean excludeThree = true;
    boolean excludeFour = false;
    boolean excludeFive = false;

    //If this was an Object I would set something like object
    print(helperMethod2(excludeOne ? null : testObject1,
            excludeTwo ? null : testObject2,
            excludeThree ? null : testObject3, // Can I skip this argument if excludeThree = true?
            excludeFour ? null : testObject4,
            excludeFive ? null : testObject5)
    );

}

public static Object[] helperMethod2(Object... items)
{
    List<Object> returnItems = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] != null) {
            returnItems.add(items[i]);
        }
    }

    return returnItems.toArray();
}

private static void print(Object... items)
{

    for (Object item : items) {
        System.out.println(((TestObject) item).getVar());
    }
}

public static class TestObject
{
    private String var;

    public TestObject(String var)
    {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public String getVar()
    {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(String var)
    {
        this.var = var;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is very specific to String data, but my question was actually more general than that. Perhaps I should have used a more complex data model in my example. This would not work with complex objects where I need to determine if a particular property is to be included.

Comment: I do think I need to rethink my whole approach, though, as my ultimate goal is just to be able to output a `TableView` to CSV and I've not been able to find any way to do so in a generic, reusable way.

Comment: True @Zephyr. I was more trying to put out ideas. I will update the answer.